# css align text in input vertically to top

Tags: html, css, input

Which is the best way to vertical align of text in tall text input?

```
<input type="text" class="bigbox" value="Some Text"/>

.bigbox{
    height:400px;
    line-height:400px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

which practice is best to set text alignment in input[text] ? not in textarea but text...

http://jsfiddle.net/DjT37/111/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DjT37/113/)

I am not sure about the best but at least this will  work

```
.bigbox{

    padding:0 5px 400px;
}
```

Comment: and what the difference? i need to top!

Comment: see my apdated fiddle. It is aligned to top.Last time I just didn't update link

Comment: Why downwoting my post? if it doesn't work or  whatever drop a comment and provide a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by only using padding to give your input a height

```
.bigbox{
    padding: 0 5px 400px
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/DjT37/114/

Comment: Why downwoting this post?

Comment: Because what's the point of aligning the text to the top if you have a large box in which you can only write on the first line?

Answer (score -2):

You could always fake it using a container `div` and some javascript (i used jQuery) to handle clicking. Note that the removal and then setting of the input's `value` in the javascript is to force the focus cursor to the end of the text. Feel free to just use `.focus()` if this isnt a requirement for you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="bigbox">
    <input type="text" class="bigboxinner" value="Some Text"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bigbox{
    height:400px;
    line-height:400px;
    padding:0 5px;
    font-size:16px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:text;
}
.bigboxinner{
    border:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    outline:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('.bigbox').on('click', function(){
        var inner = $(this).find('input.bigboxinner');
        var tempval = inner.val();
        inner.val('').focus().val(tempval);
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DjT37/116/)**

Comment: What is the point of using this trash wrapper, jquery and handle clickEvent when you can do it just with css a line of css codee?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve the same result for many questions. this solution shows one way of achieving what was asked. OP is quite welcome to use any of the suggested solutions at their disposal. There is no need to be insulting :)

Comment: He asked about the best practice btw=)