# Vertically align text in select and input elements to top

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I have some `select` and `input` elements with 100% height (**the inputs must be 100% height!**) so that they fit into their table cells. These inputs can be any height and I want the text to be vertically aligned to the top so it matches column 2.

Is this possible with pure CSS? if not, are there any nice workarounds that allow me to keep using vanilla HTML inputs? I'd like to avoid using JavaScript, but don't stray from using it if that's the only option.

Note that I don't care about IE or Safari support.

```css
table {
  height: 1px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0;
}

input,
select {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 50%">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="Should be top aligned">
      </td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Should be top aligned</option>
          <option>Item 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

P.S. This is not a duplicate as my inputs have dynamic heights, so I cannot use the padding solution mentioned here [css align text in input vertically to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937433/css-align-text-in-input-vertically-to-top)

Comment: your select and input takes all the td's height.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to, but I'm trying to get the text inside that input to align to the top

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in pure CSS. vertically aligning input elements are a pain.

I've written a small script to set the value of padding-bottom to your input's height so that it stays on top. It's not the ideal way, but does the work!

```js
alignAllInputs()
    window.onresize = () => {
        alignAllInputs()
    }
    function alignAllInputs() {
        let a = document.querySelectorAll('tr td:first-child input')
        a.forEach((item) => {
            item.style.paddingBottom = 0 + 'px'
            item.style.paddingBottom = (a[0].offsetHeight - 20) + 'px'
        })
    }
```

```css
table {
    height: 1px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 0;
}

input,
select {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 50%">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="Should be top aligned">
        </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Should be top aligned</option>
                <option>Item 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem as my inputs must remain at 100% height, or at least look/behave like they are.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a little bit of JavaScript. seems to be working, but I have to admit, it's not fancy at all! @Matt